# Fading in images with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code in order to fade in and out background images on my site.

```
var image = $('#image-holder');
    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        image.css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");
        image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

but when I try:

```
  var image = $('#image-holder');
    image.fadeIn(1000, function () {
        image.css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");
        image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

The FadeIn effect does not trigger, Any ideas why? I want the background image to fade in not out.

Comment: Calling `fadeIn` from the callback of `fadeIn` doesn't make much sense.  When the `fadeIn` is complete the element is already visible and can't fade in again.

Comment: Right here you're not fading the background but the whole image-holder. Is that your intent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your image to be initially hidden if you want it to fade in :

```
var image = $('#image-holder');
image.hide().fadeIn(1000, function () {
    image.css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");
    image.fadeOut(1000); // I suppose you want fadeOut, right ?
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oDodINe/2/)

Comment: Hey Dystroy, thank you for your feedback. It was really helpful and what we were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must use `display:none;` as opposed to `opacity:0.`

in order to be able to fadeIn something .

Comment: I seem to be missing it.  Where is `opacity` being used?

Comment: in your css , open your css tags and set it by default to be : opacity:0;

Comment: Try this <style type="text/css"> #image-holder{ opacity:0; } or instead of opacity you could also use display:none

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, promise with done,

```
var image = $('#image-holder');
image.fadeIn(1000, function () {
    image.css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')").promise().done(function() {
    image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```